# What's the difference between recording commands inside and outside the render pass?

Tags: vulkan

What's the difference between recording commands inside and outside the render pass? When do I need to record commands inside the render pass?  When do I need to record commands outside the render pass?

Answer (score 3):

The specification says if a command has to be inside, outside, or can be both. The information is in the "Render Pass Scope" entry in the "Command Properties" block.

Typically, mostly only state commands can be in both render pass scopes, and it shouldn't matter; those simply only set command buffer state. So there is no dilemma.

Comment: In addition, the Vulkan Programming Guide (aka. the Vulkan Red Book) has a nice table in the appendix summarising this information for each of the `vkCmd*` functions. The first half of this table is even included currently in the [free preview on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Vulkan-Programming-Guide-Official-Learning/dp/0134464540).

Comment: I think commands recorded inside the render pass, are associated with render. Instead, generally, those recorded outside the render pass, are relevant to data preparation. Is it right?

Comment: @607 Something like that. Commands inside render pass instance are Graphics pipeline stuff, mostly `vkCmdDraw*`. Commands outside are stuff of other pipelines, like executing Compute shader or making a copy\blit. State commands (`vkCmdSet*`, `vkCmdBind*`) are usually allowed in both scopes. Pipeline barriers are allowed in both scopes, but the two uses have somewhat different meaning. Executing secondary command buffers is also allowed in both scopes.